# React Component does not render after the state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

Hello I have a problem with re rendering the component below you can see my code for the first screen within that I have a custom component:

```
class Ahelle extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            mamad:10
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor:"white"}}>
                <ScrollView>
              <CustomSlider  defaultValue={0} />
            <CustomSlider  defaultValue={this.state.mamad} disabled={true}/>
           
           <TouchableOpacity style={{width:100,height:100,alignSelf:"center"}} onPress={()=>{this.setState({mamad:20})}}><Text>dddd</Text></TouchableOpacity>
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
          
        );
    }
 
}
```

Here I have a custom component and I pass a default value for showing but when I change the state , it is not changing the value I passed as props.
here is my custom slider component and its state, props and any other details.

```
class Test extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        console.log(props)
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: props.defaultValue
          };
       
    }
    render(){
        return(

                   <Slider
    style={{width: wp("70%")}}
    value={this.state.value}
  />
                 
         )
    }
}
export default Test;
```

[SEE THE PROBLEM IN ACTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jytcu.jpg)
Thank you for your time

Comment: Code seems to be ok.Maybe you are checking props in 1st CustomSlider.

You have 2 CustomSliders. One with `defaultValue={0}` and other with `defaultValue={this.state.mamad}`

Comment: That seems like it should throw an error about changing an uncontrolled component to a controlled one. The default value shouldn't ever change. Did you mean to pass `this.state.mamad` as the value instead? **And for future reference** please post code snippets versus images, they are harder to read and aren't searchable.

Comment: no I put two as example, when I set the new state the passed value is not changing @kapilpandey

Comment: yeah , I want to change the value after doing some calculations on this page @DrewReese

Comment: @DrewReese I edited and post codes ,

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't get changed?

Comment: I think this should be like this ```onPress={()=>this.setState({mamad:20})}```. Can you create a sand box?

Comment: yeah I am sure @D10S

Comment: I am already doing the same @SolijonSharipov

Comment: Do you see the feedback from the button press (the opacity on tap)?

Comment: @em.d. What do you mean?

Comment: I console.log to check it, it is working , when I put a Text tag in the same page and change the state , it works totally fine! but when I want to changed an already passed Value it is not working

Comment: What if you don't disable the slider? Does the value update then and you see the (possible) react warning?

Comment: @em.d can you also add your custom slider?

Comment: @em.d don’t you want to use state manager?

Comment: @DrewReese I am editing my post , its being enabled or disabled doesn't change anything at all

Comment: @SolijonSharipov I am editting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slider component never does anything with updated prop values that are passed. Coincidentally, it's also a react anti-pattern to store passed props in local component state. You can, and should, consume them directly. Just pass `this.state.mamad` to the `value` prop and consume. You can also pass along any additional props by spreading them in to the slider component.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Slider
        style={{ width: wp("70%") }}
        value={this.props.value}
        {...this.props}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Usage

```
<CustomSlider value={this.state.mamad} disabled={true} />
```

If you *really* wanted to store the passed `defaultValue` prop and keep it updated, then implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function. Note, this is ***not*** the recommended solution.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log(props);
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: props.defaultValue
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { defaultValue } = this.props;
    if (prevProps.defaultValue !== defaultValue) {
      this.setState({ value: defaultValue});
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Slider style={{ width: wp("70%") }} value={this.state.value} />;
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: thank you so much , yeah I didn't pay attention to storing it in state,

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct. I tested it.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import CustomSlider from "./CustomSlider";

export default class Ahelle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mamad: 10,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        <ScrollView>
          <CustomSlider defaultValue={0} />
          <CustomSlider defaultValue={this.state.mamad} disabled={true} />

          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{ width: 100, height: 100, alignSelf: "center" }}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({ mamad: 20 });
            }}
          >
            <Text>dddd</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

CustomSlider.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

export default class CustomSlider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Text>defaultValue: {this.props.defaultValue}</Text>;
  }
}
```

Result:
[View Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moUww.gif)

Comment: It's established that `Ahelle` is functioning as expected, the question/issue is with regards to the `CustomSlider`. This doesn't address why OP's `CustomSlider` isn't rerendering.

Comment: as @DrewReese said , he said it already is working the problem is for rerendering the component after its changes